# Why do all of my hyperrefs take me to the same page?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, href

I can't reproduce this in miniature outside of my document, so I'm asking more debugging help on how I can fix it within the document I have.

The problem is, I have a section with something like:

```
First is \hyperref[P1]{Item I}, go there.  \hyperref[P2]{Next} is item 2, and finally is \hyperref[P3]{Item III}.
\newpage

%% later...
\section*{Item I}
\label{P1}
stuff
\section*{Item II}
\label{P2}
stuff
\section*{Item III}
\label{P3}
stuff
```

Suppose

- Item I,   P1 is on page 1.
- Item II,  P2 is on page 6.
- Item III, P3 is on page 20.

No matter what I change, `\hyperref[P3]{Item III}` points to page 5, instead of 20.

I have tried the following debugs:

1. *Did I actually mislabel P3 as P2?*  No, it's P3.
2. *Did I actually fail to update the original hyperref, so it still says P2?* No, it says P3.
3. *Am I sure?*  How about I call it something totally different, like LOCATION. `\hyperref[LOCATION]{Item III} \section*{Item III}\label{LOCATION}` Still points to page 5, not page 20!
4. *Is there an error I'm missing*, such as:  L`aTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`? Nope, there are no missing references.
5. *How about completely remove `\label{P2}` and see if P3 is still pointing there?*  Removed, yes, it still points to page 5, which now has zero labels intentionally pointing to it.
6. *What about debugging the pages themselves?* `\pageref{P1} \pageref{P2} \pageref{P3}` prints `2 7 21` Close enough, but this tells me in fact pageref{P2} is also incorrect.  It's not pointing at P2, but at the end of P1, just as P3 is pointing at the end of P1.

Beyond this, I have no idea how to make any refs defined after the first one work, and by that I mean point elsewhere than at page 5. What could be going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use

```
\phantomsection
\section*{<title>}
\label{<label>}
```

since there is no hyper target set with `\section*` like there is with `\section`. If you're only using `\section*` within your document, you could automate this process using

```
\let\oldsection\section % Copy \section into \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \phantomsection % Set hyper target
  \oldsection*
}
```

in your preamble

Comment: This is so reasonable I wish it were the default.  The macro helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: @Mittenchops: The default for `\section` is to issue `\refstepcounter`. This sets a `ref`erence point and also `step`s the `counter` (`section` in this case). However, with `\section*` there is no counter to step. Moreover, if you use `\label`-`\ref`, the result is the previous counter that was stepped. So, it's just that there's nothing appropriate to reference in general. The onus is therefore shifted to the end-user.

Answer (score 3):

Another approachs  with `hyperref` and `nameref` that do not need  `\phantomsection`s:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

First is \Nameref{P1}, go there. \par 
\hyperlink{X}{Here} is \nameref{P2} (\Nameref{P2}).\par
But there are a  \Nameref{P3}.\par 
And there are not three without \hyperlink{Y}{four} in page \pageref{P4}

\newpage

\section*{Item I}
\label{P1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section*{Item II}
\label{P2}\hypertarget{X}
\lipsum[21-40]
\section*{Item III}
\label{P3}
\lipsum[41-50]
\section*{Item IV}
\label{P4}
\hypertarget{Y} 
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```